# Is there a set theory that handles collections of proper classes?

Tags: set-theory

Is there a class of all classes? If not, can I define the “banana” so we have the “banana” of all classes? Is there a banana of all bananas? If I define an apple of all bananas, is there an apple of all apples. Can this go on indefinitely? Does mathematics make any sense doing this?

If I take the limit of such a process, do I get everything, ever?

Edit: If you are going to downvote, at least explain why. This is a legitimate question.

Comment: I think people are downvoting because the text of the question is not self-contained. It only makes sense if one reads the title as if it was the first paragraph of the question. You should edit it so one doesn't need to read the title to make sense of the actual question you ask.

Comment: Maybe it looks a bit strange, but after all, who cares if we name sets 'sets', classes 'classes', or bananas, apples, or whatever? I think the question is a very good one - formulated in more familiar terms, one might interpret it as the question of whether one can continue the process of extending ZFC to NBG.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing that stops you from making a set theory which contains collections of proper classes (which you may call "bananas" if you so choose) and collections of those collections ("apples") and so forth, to any finite depth.

NBG set theory (or, even better, Morse-Kelley) can be thought of as being the first level of this, giving a formal existence to classes, which would allow us to speak about bananas in the same way we speak of proper classes while working in ZFC.

However, you're not going to get a fruit of all fruits at any level in the hierarchy, at least not if your fruits are going to satisfy some kind of comprehension axiom (without which they would be of dubious utility). This is because fruit-of-all-fruits *plus* comprehension would immediately lead to Russell's paradox.

Except for the unavailability of a fruit of all fruits, why don't we usually see this carried out in practice? Mostly because it doesn't really buy us anything that is worth the aesthetic cost, and there are better ways to do it.

Doing it straightforwardly, you would need a new logical sort (or some single-sorted simulacrum thereof) for each kind of fruit you work with -- essentially you'd end up reinventing type theory as a separate "class layer" on top of ZFC. It feels unaesthetic and unmotivated to splice together two *different* plans for avoiding the paradoxes of naive set theory in this way.

You would get much the same, without the PR baggage of type theory, by interpreting the usual ZFC axioms in *higher-order logic*, which would give you higher-order classes for free as part of the logical machinery. Again, however, it would raise the question of why have Zermeloan bottom layer at all if you're happy doing things in higher-order logic (with its lack of completeness and so forth).

The preferred alternative to both of these seems to be to work in ZFC + "there is an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$", which automatically provides a transfinite fruit hierarchy above $V_\kappa$ with *no* additional technical apparatus beyond the existence of $\kappa$. This is much more convenient. In principle it is slightly more risky than assuming ZFC (whereas a *finite* fruit hierarchy with appropriate axioms would seem to be less of a risk), but it doesn't look like anyone seriously thinks ZFC+Inaccessible is *really* any less consistent than ZFC.

Comment: Very informative answer! Concerning the first solution, do you know if someone has ever worked out a conservative extension of ZFC by finitely many class/fruit-layers? Concerning the second one, is it true that (under the assumption of consistency of the type theory used) the implementation of ZFC or any other r.e. theory in FOL within higher order logic, replacing e.g. axiom schemes with class-formula parameters by single axioms with second order quantification, gives the same notion of provability?

Comment: @Hanno, (1): I haven't seen it done explicitly, but assuming that fruit is only allowed to contain the kind of fruit immediately below it in the hierarchy, it **seems** to be easy enough to posit an unrestricted comprehension axiom for each kind of fruit, and then prove the resulting system conservative over ZFC by a model-theoretic argument: Given a model $\langle M,{\in}\rangle$ for ZFC, construct a model for fruit theory by using the metatheory's $\mathcal P^n(M)$ as carriers for the fruit kinds. [But **this must be wrong** because it would make MK conservative over ZFC, which it isn't].

Comment: @Hanno (2), I'm not sure. I'm not conversant enough with the fine points of second-order logic, but I fear it may be to strong to use class parameters at the lowest level of comprehension ("the intersection of a class and a set is a set") if the second-order logic allows too large freedom in defining classes. Note that ZFC (or NBG) only allows comprehension over formulas that where all quantification is over _sets_. Hmm .. actually that's probably the answer to the bracketed misgiving in my previous comment too.

Comment: The problem with using $\mathcal P(M)$ for classes, when $M$ is just a model of $\sf ZFC$ is that if, for example, $M$ is non-standard, then $\mathcal P(M)$ will include the class of all the standard ordinals of $M$, which shouldn't be there; and if $M$ is standard then $\mathcal P(M)$ will include a bijection between $M$ and one of its ordinals, which will also be fairly wrong. To get $\sf KM$ you need to ensure that taking $\mathcal P(M)$ doesn't add "bad classes", which essentially only happens with inaccessible cardinals. (Of course you might get $\sf KM$ by choosing only *some* subsets.)

Comment: @Asaf: Hm, yes, there are complications I hadn't fully realized. We wouldn't want to end up with a subclass of a set that isn't a set, at least not if we want to use classes in the separation/replacement axioms. And if sets are in particular also classes, then we might want classes to be bananas too and then the nice stratified sort system I was imagining for the fruit begins to break down. Very well, there was a reason type theory didn't catch on. :-)

Comment: Using ZFC + inaccessibles works very well IF you're doing classical mathematics where the largest collections are basically still sets. What's driving the rebirth of the discussions about proper classes is category theory and it's growing role in mathematics. A rigorous presentation of category theory would seem to require something like proper classes and they have to be describable in more precise ways then ZFC + inaccessibles allows. This is the current problem driving these questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is another option, which is to work *internally* rather than *externally*. You are imaginging that you begin with sets, and then form classes, and then form classes of classes, etc. The challenge, as Henning Makholm points out, is that it is hard to talk about classes "from below" in this way. You end up with a type theory on top ov $V$, and it is not clear how far you can extend the "class ordinals" beyond the ordinals of $V$. For example, which ordinals "beyond $V$" can be defined from below?

But remember that the intended models of set theory with classes are of the form $V_{\kappa + 1}$, where $V_\kappa$ is a full transitive model of ZFC.

So, work internally instead. Begin with a model $M$ of ZFC + "there is a $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa$ satisfies ZFC". Then, change your viewpoint. Consider the elements of $V_\kappa$ to be "sets", the elements of $V_{\kappa + 1}$ to be "classes", the elements of $V_{\kappa + 2}$ to be "classes of classes", etc. Now you have a perfectly consistent system that allows you to study a wide collection of "transfinite classes" -- the model $M$ guarantees that everything is consistent.

The difference between the two approaches is that, in the first approach, you are pretending to live in $V_\kappa$ and are trying to look "up" at "external" classes. In the second approach, you begin with $M$, so that you look "down" at "internal" classes.

Comment: This is my preferred approach, but I have been wondering whether it might be possible to choose some reasonable subsystem $T$ of ZFC such that $T$ + "there is a $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa$ satisfies (second-order) ZFC" has the same consistency strength as (first-order) ZFC itself. This feels unlikely, though. But I'm also interested in approximations.