# Class of classes not class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's well known that $X=\{x: x\in Set, x\notin x \}$ is not a set, so set of sets may not be set, and I have been told this $X$ is a class.

But the same procedure applied to class, $Y=\{y: y\in Class,y\notin y \}$, then $Y$, a class of classes is not a class, so is there some structure *transcends* class, maybe called *upperclass*? It goes on and on and hence we need *upper upper upper... upper class*?

It's nature that we want to decide wether a thing is in some collection, so to avoid logic flaws of collection of things, we need infinite many structures?

I have wondered this for a long time but have no time diving into set theory, can someone explain a little bit without heavy use of set theory which is not familiar by most math students?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Sadly I don't know what exactly I mean by "class", it's just a collection of something, maybe sets, in my mind.

Comment: From Wiki: "a class is a collection of sets (or sometimes other mathematical objects) that can be unambiguously defined by a property that all its members share"

Comment: $Y$ doesn't look like a class, according to the definition, because not all his elements are sets, but I'm not sure it is well defined.

Comment: This leads to Russell's type theory. It has not been very popular.

Comment: In the framework of ZFC, the notion $A\in B$ is meaingfull only if $A,B$ are sets. We extend the language by introducing (proper) classes; if $\mathcal C$ is a class then the notation $A\in \mathcal C$ should be viewed as introducing a *single* combined symbol "$\in\mathcal C$" where $A\in\mathcal C$ is interpreted as "$A$ has the property ... (whatever $\mathcal C$ is about)". In this sense, classes are not really something sets are "in", nor are they "really" objects and cannot be contained easily as such. For example, there is not even a nice predicate that formalizes "... is a class".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Good point, I was thinking the same.

Comment: Related: [Is there a set theory that handles collections of proper classes?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016844/is-there-a-set-theory-that-handles-collections-of-proper-classes).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It seems in your description that "Z is a class" means "Z is a *Types*", or something like *adjectives*, for example $C=$ *type green* is a class, $c \in C$ means $c$ is of type *green* (generally it means $c$ is green in colour). So $X$ is a Type and $x \in X$ means $x$ is of type *Set* and of type $x$. (So $\{x: x\in Set,x\in x\}$ is just a confusing notation for $X$, which is actually a *Type*), and when $A$ is a set, it could also be regard as a *Type*(Or it is "actually" a *Type* in first hand).

Comment: So $y \in Y$ means y is of type Y, that means $y \in Class$ (it means y is a *Type*, Rmk: Class is a class that is of type Class) and $y\in y$ (it means “y(a Type) is of type y”). (Rmk: to be clear, a Type *green* is not of type green, since *green* itself is not green in colour),  hence Y is a *Type*, i.e. It is a class. (again $\{y: y\in Class, y\in y\}$ is just a stupid notation for Y)

Comment: Is my understanding valid?

Answer (score 1):

In category theory collections of classes are called conglomerates.  Likewise there are structures larger then conglomerates creating an unending upwards chain.  However there has been no real study of collections larger then conglomerates so no one has given them a name.

Comment: Herrlich (Category Theory. An Introduction (1973); page 12) mentions "the cartel of conglomerates". I also came across "agglomerate" once, I do not know where.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at it [simply typed](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#2). Some classes, that are not proper classes are sets, but lets put aside sets for the moment. Lets assume you have a type for individuals i and a type for properties o, then the classes have the type:

```
classes : i -> o
```

Then you have:

```
classes of classes : (i -> o) -> o

classes of classes of classes : ((i -> o) -> o) -> o

Etc..
```

In Gödels incompletness [paper](http://www.w-k-essler.de/pdfs/goedel.pdf) (*), this was called a type level, and he used numerals 1, 2, 3, ... to indicate type levels. But what happens to the sets. Lets say, the non-proper classes are the sets, so there is a mapping:

```
 s : i -> (i -> o)
```

The above mapping maps sets to their non-proper classes. But sets will not go up some levels. Although there is a power set, this is only a mapping `p : i -> i`, so that with this viewpoint we stay on level 1 with our sets. :-( :-)

(*)
On Page 176 Gödel uses the German terms:
Klassen von Individuen
Klassen von Klassen von Individuen